# Reordering the output of rollup where the subtotals are shown at the beginning or end of the respective category

Tags: postgresql, subquery, rollup, coalesce, subtotal

We would like the subtotals from rollup to show at the beginning/end of each respective category. Below is the query on the following tables we tried. However, the Coalesce is not replacing the nulls with "total" because there are no nulls or "total" showing in the output, which means the rollup did not work. Our hypothesis is that something is not working with the sequence of the script (with the sequence). We are only familiar with Postgres sql. Thank you for any suggestions!

Tables

customers table:

```
|  customer_id|customer_name|segment    |
  -----------  -----------   ----------
|1            |Bob          |Consumer   |
|2            |Mary         |Corporate  |
|3            |Bill         |Home Office|
|4            |Kathy        |Consumer   |
```

products table:

```
|product_id      |category  |sub_category|product_name            |
 --------------  ----------  -----------  -----------------------
|FUR-ADV-10000002|furniture |furnishings |Advantus Clock Ergonomic|
|FUR-BO-10000002 |furniture |bookcases   |Bush Classic Bookcase   |
|TEC-BRO-10000348|technology|copiers     |Brother Copy Machine    |
|TEC-EPS-10000053|technology|machines    |Epson Printer Red       |
|OFF-AR-10000019 |office sup|art         |BIC Highlighters Blue   |
|OFF-EAT-10000522|office sup|paper       |Eaton Comp Printout     |
```

orders tables:

```
|order_id       |product_id      |customer_id|sales |
 --------------  ---------------  ----------  -----
|AE-2016-1308551|FUR-ADV-10000002|1          |82.67 |
|AE-2016-1308552|FUR-BO-10000002 |1          |101.54|
|AE-2016-1308553|TEC-BRO-10000348|2          |79.28 |
|AE-2016-1308554|TEC-EPS-10000053|3          |101.23|
|AE-2016-1308555|OFF-AR-10000019 |4          |39.78 |
```

Query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(products.category, 'total'), COALESCE(products.sub_category, 'total') , SUM(orders.sales) AS total_sales
FROM products
        INNER JOIN orders
        ON products.product_id=orders.product_id,
        (SELECT products.category, products.sub_category, SUM (orders.sales)
        FROM orders
        INNER JOIN products
        ON orders.product_id=products.product_id
        GROUP BY
            ROLLUP (1,2)) t
        GROUP BY 1,2
        ORDER BY 3 desc;
```

Comment: please take a loock at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and provide a full [mre]

Comment: I think I see an unintended cross join there.